# C++ popen() parameter

Tags: c++, popen

I have a question about using popen() in C++.

The code below works fine and you can put "ls" directly in as the first parameter of popen().

```
FILE *fp;
char returnData[64];

fp = popen("ls","r");
if (fp == NULL){
   }
   else{
while (fgets(returnData, 64, fp) != NULL){
      fprintf( stdout, "%s", returnData  );
            }
        }
```

However, this code does not work. Why can I not use the string called command as a parameter? It is necessary to append .c_str().

```
FILE *fp;
char returnData[64];
string command = "ls";

fp = popen(command,"r"); // fp = popen(command.c_str(),"r");
if (fp == NULL){
   }
   else{
while (fgets(returnData, 64, fp) != NULL){
      fprintf( stdout, "%s", returnData  );
            }
        }
```

Could somebody explain the difference?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** You are mixing C and C++.

`popen()` is a C-API function, therefore strings are *C-strings* (`NUL` terminated array of `char`s).

You are using `std::string`, a C++ object, and there is no automatic conversion from `std::string` to `const char *`, so you have to provide that yourself, using the `c_str()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this ：string command = "ls\n";